# JsonArrayRequest Post Method isn't working

Tags: android, post, android-volley

I did not use Volley before so I'm a newbie here. I try to do a JSONArrayRequest with Post Parameters.
A PHP script will check these parameters and answer with a JSON Array which is going to displayed in a list.
But somehow the Post Parameters don't send. So my PHP script says that the post parameters are missing.

So what did I do wrong that the post parameters don't send?

Here is my code:

```
private void getPersonsData(final String PhoneNr, final String Password) {
    String url = "http://127.0.0.1:80/android_login_api/getmembers.php";
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.POST, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
            try {
                //Adding a person in the list
                if (response.length() > 0) {
                    personList.clear();
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        Person person = new Person();
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("fullname")) {
                            person.name = jsonObject.getString("fullname");
                        }
                        if (!jsonObject.isNull("location")) {
                            person.location = jsonObject.getString("location");
                        }
                        personList.add(i, person);
                    }
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());
        }
    })  {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("phonenr", PhoneNr);
            params.put("password", Password);

            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
}
```

And here are some parts of my PHP Code:

```
getmembers.php
<?php
require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
$response = array("error" => FALSE);

if (isset($_POST['phonenr']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {  //this goes on false

// receiving the post params
$phonenr = $_POST['phonenr'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$user = $db->getUserByPhonenrAndPassword($phonenr, $password);

[...]
```

Would be great when someone finds out my mistake!

Comment: Can you post your getmembers.php file so that we can see what all do you have?

Comment: I've added a part of my php code. It should be enough @SanyamJain

Comment: Where are you using getParams() ?

Comment: It's only in the 'protected Map'. Should I use it somewhere? Maybe at the Method Post call at my JsonArrayRequest? @SanyamJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal `$_POST` method in php doesn't work in volley. You need to make this in your php file.

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
$my_value = $post['param1'];
```

`param1` is value that you put in volley.

Use this :

```
final Hashmap<String,String> param1 = new Hashmap<string,string>();
param1.put("param1",your value);
```

it works for me. You can try it

```
JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Method.POST, url, **new JSonObject(param1)**, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() { . . . ..
```